# looping twice in vba?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am having excel like below,

```
  Src   Base  June  July
  Eng   STP   10    20
  Sve   STP   20    30
  GMO   SEZ   30    10
  Eng   STP   20    30
  Sve   SEZ   40    50
```

Here I want to loop all based on condition like..
       STP should be fallen in STP sheet along with addition of Eng fields in it
       SEZ should fall in SEZ sheet along with their respective columns

I am unable to loop with each case here..

My trial was like below..

```
    With Worksheets("Mktg.Effort")
    For lrow = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row
    Select Case CStr(Cells(lrow, "R").Value) 
    Case "STP"
     Worksheets("Mktg.Effort").Rows(lrow).Activate
     For lroww = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
     Select Case CStr(Cells(lroww, "A").Value)
     Case "engg"
         ' adding all eng cols 
         ' and this data should fall in STP sheet.
```

Here I am geting all Eng fields irrespective to base(STP/SEZ) condition.
I want to loop with both the conditions 
1. should check if STP/ SEZ
2. SHould check if Eng/Sve/gmo 
and accordingly i must automate data.

ENy help please. I am struck here with no idea.

Expected output:

```
     Src  Base  June  July
     Eng  STP   30    50    ' added all ENG into one row
     Sve  STP   20    30
```

Comment: It is kind of hard to understand what you want. Are you asking how to check two conditions at once? Just use `If condition1 And condition2 Then`. That would not be considered "looping twice" though because... well, you're only looping once. Using `Select Case` seems kind of overkill here unless you want to add more cases. Oh and also string comparisons are mostly case sensitive.

Comment: Some of your Cell calls are missing dots, so refer to the active sheet rather than your With block sheet

Comment: @arcadeprecinct here I want all the rows with STP in one loop and within this loop I need to again check for case if that is eng/sve/gmo If this condition is satisfied then I need to take that row as active row. 
can you please check my edited question with expected output

Comment: @chrisneilsen Can you please check my edited question with expected output so that you can help me

Comment: @ShopShop sounds like you would want to do an `If` check for STP first and then a `Select Case` for eng/sve/gmo? It also sounds like it could be done with formulas instead of vba.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct Exactly ! but I am supposed to do this in vba only :(.. 
Checking for STP and select case for eng/sve/gmo.. any help on looping structure to achive correct rows??? 
i am actully missing correct rows in this looping

Comment: Can you not just use Filters in your worksheet to achieve this? sounds like it would give you what you need without having to write VBA

Comment: @Zac Actully I am supposed to automate calculations for every month in next 12 sheets ... so thats the reason I am using vba.

Comment: If you really want to use VBA, [have a look here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx). It should give you an idea on how to use filters within your VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping twice you may loop once and then check for condition something like below:

```
With Worksheets("Mktg.Effort")
    For lrow = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row
    Select Case CStr(Cells(lrow, "R").Value)
    Case "STP"
        If CStr(Cells(lrow, "A").Value) = "Eng" Then
            ' adding all eng cols
            ' and this data should fall in STP sheet.
        ElseIf CStr(Cells(lrow, "A").Value) = "SVE" Then
            '....and so on
```